# Are there any plugins available for python's IDLE?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

Idle is just a bare-bones text editor with no support for auto-indention.
Is there any plugin for that ?

Comment: IDLE has a python-specific auto-indent feature.  In the editor, the number of spaces per indent defaults to 4 but can be customized.  Autocompletion, tooltips, and a gui debugger are among the features that go beyond 'bare bones'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use sublime text, and use package control.Then, you can use a lots of plugins and of course, auto-indention.